# QGIS changes shapefile layers in older projects to the layer in most recent project

Tags: shapefile, qgis-3

I use QGIS to draw maps in the same style for different projects (the same layer names, with the same formatting). I use 'New shapefile layer' every time.

Recently, I've found that for many (but not all) projects, if I open an older one, the layer lines I drew have vanished and when I zoom to the layer it's now the lines I drew from the most recent project (and when I check, both projects now match). Each time, this is with a file that's saved and editing was toggled off.

I guess it must be overwriting the layer somehow (but again, not for every project). Any suggestions on how to make it stop, or is the only solution giving the layers unique names for every project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When creating a new Shapefile, if you enter just a name without and extension, it will be created in your home\documents directory. If there is already an existing file, it will be overwritten without warning (this sounds like a bug...).

However, if you specify a `.shp` extension, or if you click on the 3 dots to select a file/directory, a warning will be shown that the file already exists.

[image]

[image]

[image]